# python serial write timeout

Tags: python, pyserial

I have used pyserial for a couple of days. However, a problem occurs today. I met serial write timeout. Several days before, when I used a switch, everything is OK. But today I changed for another switch. Then serial write timeout appears. I did not change any code, but the problem is actually quite severe. More seriously, the timeout not always occurs, which means that sometimes I can write in the serial successfully.

```
ser = serial.Serial( #Serial COM configuration
    port='COM5',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    rtscts=True,
    timeout=2,
    writeTimeout=5
  )
strInput = "show ver"
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()
ser.write(strInput.encode('utf-8')+b'\n')
```

I have ensured that the port is COM5 and the baudrate of the switch is 9600. Thanks a lot for answering my question.

Comment: How can you have a timeout on writing?

Comment: Increase writeTimeout value or remove the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have already tried those methods, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem recently. I found that setting `write_timeout=0` solved the issue (also, not really sure why a write timeout even exists...)

Another answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18314684/2242656) suggests the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have flow control with request to send / clear to send structure and the device you are writing to isn't responding you need the timeout for the write in order to not hang

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the interface tries to comply with RTS, CTS, DSR, or DTS signals. It is possible that if they are not properly connected, they can mysteriously affect communication through a timeout.

One solution may be to ignore their influence using `rtscts=False` and/or `dsrdtr=False` when opening the serial port in Python.